# Populating Html.Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass in an array to this dropdownlist in my Partial View:

```
<% 
    Html.DropDownList(Model.Name, Model.Options);
%>
```

The options are comma separated of course.  It's expecting an IEnumerable so not sure what I'm missing here.  It's not accepting the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<% 
    Html.DropDownList(Model.Name, new SelectList(Model.Options));
%>
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up trying just that.  I think it may work but I'm not getting anything rendered yet due to other logic that I have that's causing issues.  Let me try to resolve and see if this will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could show us more of your code such as the value of Model.Options but here is some code that may help.

```
model.Options = new SelectList(values.ToList(), "Key", "Value");

<%= Html.DropDownList(Model.Name, 
                      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)model.Options) %>
```

Comment: I'm not using ViewData...I'm passing in an object from RenderPartial helper.  Since I strongly typed my Partial View, I should be able to just use Model.  I just don't know how to create the SelectList.